# Magento 2 add custom(comment text) field in checkout shipping method

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.3.0, checkout page i wants to add custom field (Comment text field) at shipping method tab.
Please suggest me how can i do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Try this https://marketplace.magento.com/rage-delivery-date.html you requirement will fulfil by this extension

Comment: You can also use this module https://github.com/boldcommerce/magento2-ordercomments